# If $R$ is symmetric and transitive then prove that $R$ is reflexive

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be a relation on $A$ s.t $$\forall a \in A, \exists b\in A, \quad aRb$$
Prove that if $R$ is symmetric and transitive then $R$ is reflexive.

I don't know how to solve it, I just did that $$\text{Symmetric : } \forall a,b \in A,\quad aRb \implies bRa$$
$$\text{Transitive : } \forall a,b,c \in A \quad aRb \text{ and } bRc \implies aRc$$

and we want to prove $$\forall a \in A,\quad aRa.$$

Comment: Well, put the three conditions together to deduce the statement.. Use transitivity for $c=a$..

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1592652/826797) for some counter examples to your statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a\in A$. Then by hypothesis, $aRb$ for some $b\in A$.

Thus $bRa$ by symmetry. Hence, $aRb$ and $bRa$ imply $aRa$ by transitivity. Done.